# React Js: How to pass table row data as props to another page using onClick event

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jsx

I am having a table with some rows and two buttons on each row of that table (It's a JSX page). I want to pass the table row data as props to another page by clicking the buttons and display the data.
But I can't figure out how to open a page by passing the table row data on button click.

Point no 2 and 3 where I get confused.

Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Following is the simplified code:

> ```
> import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
> import { Icon, Segment, Table, Dropdown } from 'semantic-ui-react';
> import { SalesInvoice } from './invoices';
> import { PDF } from './pdfs';
> ```

1. Declaring Example table

> ```
> const PurchasesListTable = () => {   
>  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
>
>
> const tableData = [
>   {
>     ServiceNo:'SER_001',
>     ServiceName: "Laptop Repair",
>     Cost: 100,
>     Location: 'Kolkata',
>     id: 1
>   },
>   {
>     ServiceNo:'SER_002',
>     ServiceName: "Mobile Repair",
>     Cost: 50,
>     Location: 'Mumbai',
>     id: 2
>   },
>   {
>     ServiceNo:'SER_003',
>    ServiceName: "TV Repair",
>     Cost: 70,
>     Location: 'Delhi',
>     id: 5
>   },
>   {
>     ServiceNo:'SER_004',
>     ServiceName: "PC Repair",
>     Cost: 120,
>     Location: 'Chennai',
>     id: 4
>   }]
> ```

2. Creating two methods for seperate pages and trying to fetch the data from onclick event (point no.3)

> ```
> const handleSalesView = (data) => {
>   let payload;
>   payload = data
>   return <SalesInvoice data={data} />
> }
>
> const handlePDFView = (data) => {
>   let payload;
>   payload = data
>   return <PDFData data={data} />
> }
>   return (  
>   <Segment>
>     <Segment attached>
>       <Table compact celled definition unstackable>
>         <Table.Header>
>           <Table.Row>
>               <Table.HeaderCell>id</Table.HeaderCell>
>               <Table.HeaderCell>Service No</Table.HeaderCell>
>               <Table.HeaderCell>Service Name</Table.HeaderCell>
>               <Table.HeaderCell>Cost</Table.HeaderCell>
>               <Table.HeaderCell>Location</Table.HeaderCell>
>               <Table.HeaderCell>Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
>           </Table.Row>
>         </Table.Header>
>         <Table.Body>
>           {
>             loading ?
>             <Table.Row>
>               <Table.Cell colSpan='6'>
>                 <center style={{padding: '140px'}}><Icon name="spinner" color="grey" loading size="huge"/></center>
>               </Table.Cell>
>             </Table.Row>
>             :
>            tableData && tableData!==undefined?
>             tableData?.map((row, idx) => (
>               <PurchaseRow key={idx} row={row} id={idx} onSelect = {setSelectedRow}/>
>             ))
>             :
>             <Table.Row>
>               <Table.Cell colSpan='6'>
>                 <center style={{padding: '40px', color: 'grey'}}><h1>No data</h1></center>
>               </Table.Cell>
>             </Table.Row>
>           }
>         </Table.Body>
>       </Table>
>     </Segment>    
>   </Segment>   
>   ); 
> }
> ```

3. I have collected the row data (which is working fine) but not able to pass the data to the methods (point no.2)

> ```
>   const PurchaseRow = ({id, row, onSelect}) => {   
>   const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);   
>   return(
>   <>
>     <Table.Row key={id}>
>       <Table.Cell>{row.id}</Table.Cell>
>       <Table.Cell>{row.ServiceNo}</Table.Cell>
>       <Table.Cell>{row.ServiceName}</Table.Cell>
>       <Table.Cell>{row.Cost}</Table.Cell>
>       <Table.Cell>{row.Location}</Table.Cell>
>       <Table.Cell>
>       <Dropdown icon='ellipsis vertical' floating direction="left" className='icon'>
>           <Dropdown.Menu>
>             <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=> { onSelect(row) }} style={{color: '#145ba7'}}>View Sales</Dropdown.Item>
>             <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=> { onSelect(row) }}  style={{color: '#E36005'}}>PDF</Dropdown.Item>
>           </Dropdown.Menu>
>       </Dropdown>
>       </Table.Cell>
>    </Table.Row>
>   </>   
>   )}
> export {PurchasesListTable}
> ```

Comment: I realized you were returning component in the function so updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can try this, I realized you were returning component in the function so updated my answer.
You'll also need to implement onCancel event so when you close the page and `setIsSalesView` to `false` or `setIsPDFView` to `false` and `setSelectedRow` to `null`

In point 2

```
const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState(null);
const [isSalesView, setIsSalesView] = useState(false);
const [isPDFView, setIsPDFView] = useState(false);

  return (  
  <Segment>
    {isSalesView && selectedRow && <SalesInvoice data={selectedRow} /> }
    {isPDFView && selectedRow && <PDFData data={selectedRow} /> }
    <Segment attached>
      <Table compact celled definition unstackable>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
              <Table.HeaderCell>id</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Service No</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Service Name</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Cost</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Location</Table.HeaderCell>
              <Table.HeaderCell>Actions</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>
        <Table.Body>
          {
            loading ?
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.Cell colSpan='6'>
                <center style={{padding: '140px'}}><Icon name="spinner" color="grey" loading size="huge"/></center>
              </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
            :
          tableData && tableData!==undefined?
            tableData?.map((row, idx) => (
              <PurchaseRow key={idx} row={row} id={idx} onSelect={setSelectedRow} handleSalesView={setIsSalesView} handlePDFView={setIsPDFView} />
            ))
            :
            <Table.Row>
              <Table.Cell colSpan='6'>
                <center style={{padding: '40px', color: 'grey'}}><h1>No data</h1></center>
              </Table.Cell>
            </Table.Row>
          }
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    </Segment>    
  </Segment>   
  ); 
}
```

In point 3

```
const PurchaseRow = ({id, row, onSelect, handleSalesView, handlePDFView}) => {   
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);   
  return(
  <>
    <Table.Row key={id}>
      <Table.Cell>{row.id}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{row.ServiceNo}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{row.ServiceName}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{row.Cost}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>{row.Location}</Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell>
      <Dropdown icon='ellipsis vertical' floating direction="left" className='icon'>
          <Dropdown.Menu>
            <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=> { onSelect(row); handleSalesView(true);}} style={{color: '#145ba7'}}>View Sales</Dropdown.Item>
            <Dropdown.Item onClick={()=> { onSelect(row); handlePDFView(true);}}  style={{color: '#E36005'}}>PDF</Dropdown.Item>
          </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      </Table.Cell>
   </Table.Row>
  </>   
  )}
export {PurchasesListTable}
```